# jQuery timer plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I am trying to run a jquery timer using libraries from here:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-countdown

When I try to load the page the timer is not shown

**This is my code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" 
     href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" 
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-
    countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.js">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-
   countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.css">

  </head>
 <body>
<p>hi</p>
 <div id="getting-started"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#getting-started').countdown('2017/01/01', function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
  });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVaj7.png)

Comment: Maybe it's not the cause, but you should use `<link>` tag for including CSS.

Comment: please look at my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the JS you are referencing is having issues.
Try referring it from here https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js

And change CSS reference to link since it is not a script

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is what you need to write

```
$('#getting-started').countdown('2017/01/01', function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/312201p5/2/)

Comment: You JS file should be referred with in script tag. Only CSS should be link. Also your Js file is having issues hence refer it from the link I provided

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.2/jquery.countdown.css">`
My files currently look like that I think according to you thats ok but I got the same error I show on the image

Comment: I changed both of my JS from href to src and that worked but I would like to know why? btw THANKS A LOT

Comment: btw how can I set this timer to a 2 hour timer?

Comment: You can pass whatever time/days you want to show in countdown as a parameter . I have changed the format of the counter to display in H:M:S ..      var today = new Date();
today.setHours(today.getHours() + 2);
$('#getting-started').countdown(today, function(event) {
   $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
});